# How can I create a shelve-set in Intellij without shelving my changes?

Tags: intellij-idea, shelveset

I enjoy creating shelve-sets as little check points in the code but I was wondering if there was a way to create a shelve-set in IntelliJ without actually shelving the changes? I can't seem to find a way in options and some extensive googling has brought me no results.

Comment: There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171009

Comment: Ah, that's what I was wondering. Thank you.